# How to "list" text in columns in iOS?

Tags: ios

Basically, I wish to list some text like so, in a column view:

```
Item        Colour       Quantity
Glasses     Black        3
```

It's not for user-input, more towards the user reading it. I know this can be accomplished via the use of labels, however, this does tend to get tedious. I have the text written up in a word document, tried to copy and paste it into a UITextView and mess around with the attributes, I get 99% close however the last "column" seems to always give me an issue.

Can anyone potentially shed some light onto how I can do this with ease?

P.S- I will probably have 10 "lists" each different.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically three good possibilities.

1) You give it a try using labels

2) You take a UICollectionView or

3) some UITableViews side by side

I had the same problem and I decided to go with option 1)

Create a method which needs a 2d String array as input.
Determine the ScreenSize of the device.

```
func createRows(textName: [[String]])
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        if self.columnArrayActive || self.columnArray1.isEmpty
        {
            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            let screenWidth = screenSize.width
            self.ScrollViewMain.contentSize.height = CGFloat(30 * textName.count))
```

Now create two for loops to iterate through the array.
Create the labels and modify them.

```
            for i1 in 0..<textName.count
            {
                var columnArray = [UILabel]()

                for i2 in 0..<textName[i1].count
                {
                    columnArray.append((UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat((Int(screenWidth) / 9) * i2 - Int(screenWidth / 128)), (CGFloat(30 * i1) - modifyY), CGFloat(Int(screenWidth) / 8), 30))))
                    columnArray[i2].text = textName[i1][i2]
                    columnArray[i2].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

I have additionally structured the rows with two different colors for a better reading experience.

```
                    if i1 == 0
                    {
                        columnArray[i2].backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(1), green: CGFloat(0.35), blue: CGFloat(0.35), alpha: CGFloat(1))
                    } else {
                    if self.rowSwitcher
                    { columnArray[i2].backgroundColor = settings.vari.color1 as? UIColor}
                    else
                    { columnArray[i2].backgroundColor = settings.vari.color2 as? UIColor}
                    }
                    self.scrollViewMain.addSubview(columnArray[i2])
                }
                if i1 != 0
                {
                    if self.rowSwitcher
                    { self.rowSwitcher = false }
                    else
                    { self.rowSwitcher = true }
                }
                self.columnArray1.append(columnArray)
            }
            self.columnArrayActive = false
```

This part of the code is used when you already have created your list but you need to update the values of the labels.

```
        } else {
            for i3 in 0..<textName.count
            {
                for i4 in 0..<textName[i3].count
                {
                    self.columnArray1[i3][i4].text = textName[i3][i4]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to define some global or class variables to get it work:

1)columnArray1 : [[UILabel]]

2)columnArrayActive : Bool

3)scrollViewMain : UIScrollView!

You create in the Interface Builder a UIScrollView filling you screen.
Then you create constraints.
Afterwards you create a reference to your class and in viewDidLoad you add:

```
scrollViewMain = self.delegate
```

This means that your class needs of course to inherit from UIScrollViewDelegate!

The result looks like this:

[image: potrait]

[image: landscape]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can draw text into a graphics context. For read-only text, this is definitely an option I would consider. Another option which might work for you is [text containers in Text Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html).